# table-design for addbuddy module

Tags: php, database-design

I'm rebuilding an add-buddy module and I have a question about the database table design.

In the current version i have a design like this:

> id | user1_id | user2_id | status

Each time an user invites another, two rows are created, in one row the current users id is placed in the field user1_id, in the next row the users id is placed in user2_id, which enables me to use a rather simple MySQL query in the list mode of the module:

`WHERE a.id=b.user2_id AND b.status = 1 AND b.user1_id = '".$get_user."'`

Now, i try to find another way to build this, as i would prefer to have only one row for each friendship, instead of the currently used two.

I have come up with several approaches for table-design and building the logged in users buddylist and i would like to see your opinion about this.

1. using only one field "ids" for both users ids, comma-seperated. in the select-query i check if the field ids contains the logged in users id, probably using LIKE for that. Than in the while loop i would remove the current users id from the field with `str_replace($current_user_id, '', $row['id']);`
2. one row, with fields id1 and id2, using a simple OR in the select-query, in the while loop for building the list i would place an if-statement:

`if ($row['id1'] == $current_user_id) use $row['id2'] else use $row['id1']`

1. using two select-queries with UNION like this:

   `(select * from users where id1 = user_id)
    UNION
   (select * from users where id2 = user_id)`

What do you think of this approaches would be the best for this kind of thing, or do you have another idea?

Edit: thought i would have found an easy solution for table and a matching query, but didnt work, so i deleted it.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain further how you end up with two rows? I could understand easily that if an invite is made, the one who invited (`user1_id`) will be inserted together in the same row as the one he invited (`user2_id`) and the `status` would be a value that can changed depending on user2_id's response, is this somehow correct? As for your query, what is table a and b?

Comment: As i said, the two rows allows to use a quiet simple select-query in the list-mode (where user1 = $current_user_id), as one of both rows would always be matching user1 = $current_user_id. As mentioned, i could extend the select-query with an OR statement (where user1 = $current_user OR user2 = $current_user), maybe i could sth like uid1 AS userid, uid2 AS userid in the select, is that possible? Or would UNION be better here? Table.a contains username and so on of the users, table.b is the actual buddy-table, actually not so important here.

Comment: ...is it possible to use sth like "uid1 AS userid, uid2 AS userid" in the select, so in the while-loop i would always have the right field to be displayed?

Comment: That would make the query simple, but from a DBA perspective, it's really not a good way to do it. I was going to give a similar answer like @Pateman's because one row for each user1-to-user2 relationship is the way to go, and grabbing the relationships as his query did makes it easier. In fact, if (only if) you ever had to get the list of established 'friendships' you can easily join tables or the users table to itself to get desired results. All in all, what needs to be modified first is `how` you save your data. If you want, post the script and we'll follow suit...

Comment: `use sth like "uid1 AS userid, uid2 AS userid"...`  by right field, you mean the field on the right.. rather.. `uid2`?

Comment: @noym, no i mean the field containing the uid of the OTHER user, not the currently logged in user, whos buddylist is generated. the thing what this is about is, that the field user2_id could contain the uid of the buddy OR of the current user, the later mentioned you would not need in the buddylist.

Comment: updated my post. please check and comment there... we need to take a step back and review your requirements..

Answer (score 1):

Like @Nonym suggested, you could use the `status` column. Set `-1` when the friendship is awaiting confirmation, `0` when the friendship has been denied, and `1` if the friendship is accepted.

Getting a list of all friends for a certain user ID is as simple as calling:

`SELECT user2_id FROM users WHERE status = 1 AND user1_id = <your user id>` .

Since your database is going to be filled with denied invitations, you could have a cronjob running every 24 hours or so, which will delete all denied invitations, reducing space. A query like

`DELETE FROM users WHERE status = 0`

would be of use. Actually, you can move even further and add another field called `date`, which will indicate the date when the request was sent and in the same cronjob include deleting records with `status = -1`, which have been in the table for too long.

**EDIT**

Just like @jayden said, the `user_id`'s may be mixed, so the best way is to keep these two consistent. Like `user1_id` being always the current user and `user2_id` being the receiver. And to know, who invited who, add another field like `addressee` or any other (probably) more suitable name, which will hold the id of the user who initiated the request.

Comment: You're right! In the end, good table-design-to-table-purpose should be one of the first objectives

Comment: Pateman, the select you suggested is actually the one im using now, but this approach is only working with two rows for one friendship, because user2_id could contain the id of the current user aswell, depending on which user has invited the other user.

Comment: @noym, is that so? have you dealt with something like this before? maybe you read again.

Comment: @pateman hey, i thought about your suggestion a bit and thanks for your suggestion. Not sure though, if i understand what you mean with it. this is not about whos receiver and whos sender, you know?!

Comment: @jayden, what I mean is that using my suggestion you don't need to check which column (`user1_id` or `user2_id`) contains the id of the user you want to collect buddies of. The auxiliary field is just for the sake of checking who initiated the friendship (i.e. sent the request).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, and while waiting for a response to the comment, I'll have to say this as soon as possible:

Approach # 1: Try to avoid doing this as much as possible. Data should be what it is; data, so refrain (when you can) from putting logic into the data. Put your logic perhaps in a `view`, `function` or `stored procedure` :)

[edit]
Now I'm confused. Let's take a step back, shall we?

First, you have a table that appears this way (and I will just make a rough 'sketch' of it) :

```
TABLE USERS
id (auto increment?)
user1_id (the one initiating the friendship invite)
user2_id (the one user1_id is inviting to form a friendship)
status (the status of the friendship; like
```

A record is added to the table `USERS` when:

`A user, whose id goes into user1_id invites someone whose id then goes into user2_id , and a status is set to mean something like 2 if an invite had just been sent, and 1 if it was accepted or perhaps 0 if it was rejected, etc`

What part/s in the above statements is/are incorrect?

[edit] part ii:

Everything aside, if it comes down to:

**Get all records where the viewing user is either an initiator (user1_id) or is a recipient of a buddy request (user2_id)**

Then you don't really need a `union`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN user1_id = <Id_Of_Viewing_User> THEN user2_id
        WHEN user2_id = <Id_Of_Viewing_User> THEN user1_id
    END AS user_id
FROM users 
WHERE 
    user1_id = <Id_Of_Viewing_User>
    OR
    user2_id = <Id_Of_Viewing_User>
```

Can you try the SQL above? That way, you won't need to worry about the programming part. Whatever comes out in `user_id` is the id of someone who has either requested to be the viewing user's friend of someone the viewing user requested to be a buddy with.

Is this... anywhere.. anywhere at all.. near what you want?

Comment: no, sorry, that is not quiet what i mean. it is a buddy-modul, where you can add buddies. the thing is, you cant know in which field the user-id of the user, whos profile you are watching, is placed in, you definitively cant know that. there are solutions for this, as posted above, im just not sure, which is the most efficient (in terms of performance) using union, or an OR-statement with if-clauses in every turn of the while-loop to get the right field.

Comment: @jayden : could you try my 'latest' edit? I provided the SQL you can use. If you feed it an id.. the `user_id` column will not have the id you provided, but everyone else's (by everyone, anyone who is in that buddy table as user1 or user2 id) Give it a shot, will yah? :)

Comment: hey nonym that looks nice, thank you for your ambition. so now there are four possible methods to use: 1. the one u just posted, 2. two very simple selects with union, 3. using or-statement within select and use if-clause in the while-loop, 4. use one field for both ids, and remove the uid of the list-owner with str_replace. You mentioned that sharing one field for two values might not be such a good idea, so from the remaining three methods, which should be the fastest? any Ideas?! thanks and have a nice evening.

Comment: Sadly, your last question puts me in a tough position, because my opinion will somewhat lead to the query I used being the fastest. But anyway, it is my opinion, and for your benefit, I would definitely be glad to be corrected. -> I stand by my first vote against #4, so that's that.. #3 will use not just SQL but your PHP code as well just to filter properly, and I don't see how that should be any advantage when you can grab the results right in SQL already. #2 is something I don't think will be faster because it will query the table twice. #1 queries one table just once. :)